# How to read the value of associative array inside an array from parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-2.8

I have my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    housing_type: 
      - 1: 220
        2: 180
        3: 280
```

I want to fetch the value of `housing_type[1]` ie. 220 from inside the controller, so I use

```
$this->container->getParameter('housing_type[$val]');
```

But it says

```
parameter 'housing_type[$val]' must be defined
```

Any ideas how do I fetch the value of array inside an array?

Comment: You need to grab the entire array.  $this->container->getParameter('housing_type')[$val] should work.

Comment: you sir are a genius :). It works